# How to select which PowerPoint to edit in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am building a report where users will take tables from Excel and paste them into a PowerPoint.  Since I won't know what the users will name the PowerPoint, I am giving them two options.  If the one they want is not open, they will open it.  What I am having trouble is if the one they want is already open, how can I have them select it?  This is what I have so far:

```
Dim ans As Integer
Dim pptName As String
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim arr() As String
Dim j As Variant

ans = MsgBox("Is the PowerPoint already open?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If ans = vbYes Then
    For Each myPres in ppt.Presentations
        Redim Preserve arr(j)
        arr(j) = myPres.Name
        j = j + 1
    Next

    'How to use the names of all the current ppts in the array and let a user select which one from that list
    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations(1)
Else
    MsgBox ("Please choose PowerPoint to open.")
    'openDialog is a function I have already created
    pptName = openDialog()
    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)
End If
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Loop though all open presentations, get all their names, and let the use choose one

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my code that includes an array of all the open PowerPoint names.  How do I let the user choose one of them?

Comment: build a small user_form with a ListBox populated with the array, and one the user selects a certain item from the ListBox set it as the needed Presentation

Comment: Shai's suggestion is the most robust, but if your users are trainable, you can have them make the presentation they want to use the active presentation then do Set myPres=ppt.ActivePresentation

Comment: @BH57 no feedback to the answer and code I've provided below ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little long, But I've included the code in the regular Module, and also the `User_Form`.

***Code Module***

```
Option Explicit

Public PPTFileName As String  '<-- defined as Public, will get it from the User_Form's ListBox

Sub SelectPPTPresentation()

' === this loop through all open PowerPoint Presentations is using Late Binding
' === to avoid future problems when working with multiple Office Versions

Dim ppApp                               As Object
Dim ppPres                              As Object
Dim ObjPres                             As Object

If MsgBox("Is the PowerPoint already open?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ppApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No PowerPoint is open!"        
    Else
        If ppApp.Presentations.Count > 0 Then ' check that at least 1 Presentation is open
            For Each ObjPres In ppApp.Presentations ' loop through all open presnetations (
                UserForm1.OpenPPPres_LB.AddItem ObjPres.FullName '<-- add their full names to the User_Form ListBox
            Next ObjPres
        End If
    End If
    UserForm1.Show '<-- show the User_Form with the ListBox of all open PPT presentations

    ' loop through all open presnetations (check Full Name: Path and name)
    For Each ObjPres In ppApp.Presentations
        If StrComp(ObjPres.FullName, PPTFileName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set ppPres = ObjPres  ' <-- set the current PPT pres to the selected Item from the ListBox
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ObjPres
    MsgBox "Selected Presentation is " & ppPres.Name ' <-- just for confirmation >> show Name (without Path)    

Else  ' <-- you will need to modify this section to fit the upper section

'    MsgBox ("Please choose PowerPoint to open.")
'    'openDialog is a function I have already created
'    pptName = openDialog()
'    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)
'       
End If

End Sub
```

***User_Form Code*** the event is under the "OpenPPPres_LB" ListBox `DblClick` event:

```
Private Sub OpenPPPres_LB_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim i           As Long

For i = 0 To OpenPPPres_LB.ListCount - 1
    If OpenPPPres_LB.Selected(i) Then
        PPTFileName = OpenPPPres_LB.List(i) ' <-- save the PPT filename
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

*Screen-shot of the User_Form populated with the current Open Presentations*:

[image]